# Can't mount disk before nfs server starts

Tags: systemd, nfs

I have an NFS server with the following /etc/exports line(the only one): `/data/Nextcloud devserver.emcci(rw,sync,all_squash,anonuid=33,anongid=33)`

But the problem is that data is on another disk than the root filesystem. And nfs-server status says that can't find the /data/Nextcloud folder. So I think that nfs-server.service is running before the disk can be mounted. Here you have the status output:
[image: status output]

I have tried some solutions I have found on internet. Like adding `x-system.d.before=nfs-server.service` in fstab file: `UUID=0618335b-3595-4428-aab5-5da1a1d3f450 /data           auto    nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show,x-system.d.before=nfs-server.service 0 0`. I have tried also with `x-system.d.before=nfs-kernel-server.service`.

I have tried also to add `After=data.mount` to the system.d unit, but had no effect:
[image: cat output]

What I'm doing wrong? If I start the services manually it works, but not at boot time.

Thanks for your time,

Héctor

EDIT: I have found that adding `Before=nfs-server.service` on `data.mount` it works! Even deleting all the other modifications. So, telling the system to mount the disk before sharing it works perfectly, telling it to share it after being mounted does nothing... Does anyone know why?

Haven't post it as an answer because for me isn't a complete answer without knowing why.

Comment: It's interesting that "After=local-fs.target" didn't work for the nfs-server service. I would have thought that local-fs implied mounting of all the local filesystems.